# How can I install tensorflow when I'm getting UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict: ...?

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I'm trying to install tensorflow onto a Mac. Whether I use pip or the anaconda interface to try to install it I have the same problem. Progress halts at `solving package specifications` and after a long while I eventually get a `UnsatisfiableError` message.

I'm new to Mac OS, and I've only installed anaconda before on a a Windows 10 machine. I never used the anaconda interface before now, nor pip to install further packages which conflicted with those already installed by anaconda.

When I googled this issue I found a few solutions, the most popular of which was to upgrade anaconda, however, all my packages are up to date.

This is the full error message I'm getting:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in 
conflict:
  - anaconda==2018.12=py37_0 -> cython==0.29.2=py37h0a44026_0
  - anaconda==2018.12=py37_0 -> mkl-service==1.1.2=py37hfbe908c_5
  - anaconda==2018.12=py37_0 -> numexpr==2.6.8=py37h7413580_0
  - anaconda==2018.12=py37_0 -> scikit-learn==0.20.1=py37h27c97d8_0
  - tensorflow
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

Do I have to uninstall the problem packages to get tensorflow to install, or is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now, tensorflow does not support python3.7, you need to use python 3.6

try:

```
conda create -n tf_env python=3.6 tensorflow
conda activate tf_env
```

This will create a new virtual environment with python 3.6 and tensorflow installed in it. [I'll admit now I don't have a mac to verify, but it should work on a mac like it does on linux.]

Comment: How can this workaround be undone when/if tensorflow support catches up with python 3.7? Update anaconda?

Also, is this really what's causing packages to not be compatible? Or is it just a secondary problem I didn't know about?

Comment: This is creating a new virtual environment with python=3.6. If you run conda deactivate you'll be back in the base environment with python 3.7, or you can create a new virtual environment and specify python=3.7 tensorflow for that new environment (when python 3.7 is supported)

Comment: The conflict is all the packages listed above (cython==0.29.2=py37h0a44026_0) require python 3.7 (that is the py37 in the name) while tensorflow doesn't have a package for python 3.7

Comment: Thats great. Is it possible to use tensorflow in pycharm or another ide using a virtual environment like this, or is it just for the terminal?

Comment: I have never used pycharm before, but googling "pycharm and anaconda" I found this link that explains how to point pycharm at an anconda virtual environment: https://medium.com/@GalarnykMichael/setting-up-pycharm-with-anaconda-plus-installing-packages-windows-mac-db2b158bd8c